# Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

suddenly eclipse started to give that error.

**"Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log"**

This is my xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context=".Generate" >


    <View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/generatetv1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/generatetv1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#90000000" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/generate_dukkan"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/generate_direnisci_adi"
    android:background="@drawable/extension" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/generatebtn3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="Buradan Git" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/generatebtn2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/generatebtn1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="Button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/generatebtn1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/generatebtn3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="generate_dukkan" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/generate_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/generatetv1"
    android:text="DigitalClock"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/generatetv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/generatebtn2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/generate_puan"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/generate_puantext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/generate_seviye"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/generate_seviye"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/generate_time"
    android:text="Puan "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/generate_puan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/generate_seviye"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/generate_seviye"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/generate_time"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/generate_puantext"
    android:background="#242424"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="200"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/generate_seviye"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/generatetv1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/destekimg"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/generate_seviyetext"
    android:background="#242424"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/generate_direnisci_adi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/generate_seviye"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/generate_seviye"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/generate_time"
    android:text="Direnisci Adi"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/maskeimg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/generate_seviye"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/eldivenimg"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/text_field"
    android:src="@android:drawable/spinner_background" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/eldivenimg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/generate_dukkan"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/maskeimg"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/text_field"
    android:src="@android:drawable/spinner_background" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/destekimg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/eldivenimg"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eldivenimg"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/text_field"
    android:src="@android:drawable/spinner_background" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/generate_seviyetext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/generate_time"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Sevİye "

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/generate_dukkan"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/generate_time"
    android:layout_below="@+id/generate_puan"
    android:background="@drawable/dukkan_img"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

what can I do to fix this?

Comment: You need to post the stacktrace of the error. You can get it following the instructions you posted in your question: *details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log*. Edit your question and add this info.

Comment: it says only: " Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is caused because there is a circular reference is the layout parameters.

For example when view B is layout_below View A, view A can't reference view B anymore in it's below, alignRight etc. This can also exist between multiple views: A references B references C. In that scenario C can't reference A because of a circular dependency.

You'll need to evaluate the references again. Does it give you a line number?

Edit:

When I remove these 2 from `android:id="@+id/generate_seviye"` it works:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/generatetv1"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/destekimg"
```

But you probable need to do some fixing of the layout and check the references.

@+id/view2 has:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/generatetv1"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/generatetv1"
```

Which seems wrong to me.

I know you should use as little layouts as possible, but adding one linearlayout will probably make it a lot easier

Comment: its not giving any information. I refactored an id and it happened.

Comment: thanks, removing those two has worked but I still don't understand why is it happened. I only refactored an id of a TextView.