# Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, layout, error-handling, circular-dependency

> Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
>   Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogException raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Blockquote

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" 
android:id="@+id/layout">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_style"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/accelerometer_text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:text="@string/x_axis"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_xyz"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/x_axis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#00f" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/y_axis"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_xyz"
    android:text="@string/y_axis"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/y_axis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/x_axis"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#0f0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#f00" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_xyz"
    android:text="@string/z_axis"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/z_axis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/y_axis"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#00f"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#0f0" />
```

Comment: Circular references should **never** occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add circular dependancy between view-

Remove one line from your code -

```
remove - `android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"`
```

from  below view -

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/y_axis"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/x_axis"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:background="#0f0"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textColor="#f00" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Circular reference in the Relative Layout not allowed or it's invalid.

For example when view B is layout_below View A, view A can't reference view B anymore in it's below, alignRight etc. This can also exist between multiple views: A references B references C. In that scenario C can't reference A because of a circular dependency.

Get more details from here:

[Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949973/exception-raised-during-rendering-circular-dependencies-cannot-exist-in-relativ)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're being ambiguous with your alignments, in other words, somewhere in your .xml you're telling the compiler to do 2 things with a layout that contradict each other. You're telling `y_axis` TextView to be **above** `textView4` while at the same time you're telling `textView4` to be **below** `textView3`. Both of these can't be true and therefore is creating the circular dependency, one of these needs to be changed.